# Objective-c object releasing patterns

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, properties

I've run into some unfamiliar Objective-c memory management code.  What is the difference between:

```
// no property declared for myMemberVariable in interface
id oldID = myMemberVariable;
myMemberVariable = [MyMemberVariable alloc] init];
[oldID release];
```

and:

```
// (nonatomic, retain) property is declared for myMemberVariable in interface
self.myMemberVariable = [[MyMemberVariable alloc] init];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is technically incorrect, but the first probably stems from someone yet to embrace Objective-C 2.0 property syntax. It was added relatively recently if you're a long-time OS X developer (or an even-longer-time NextStep/OS X developer), so you do see people not using it without gaining any benefit or detriment by not doing so.

So the first is basically the same as:

```
[myMemberVariable release];
myMemberVariable = [[MyMemberVariable alloc] init];
```

Given that you have a 'retain' property, the correct version with the setter should be:

```
// this'll be retained by the setter, so we don't want to own what we pass in
self.myMemberVariable = [[[MyMemberVariable alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, you've got an instance variable. In the second, a property with auto memory management attributes (as indicated by the retain).

In the first example, you're allocating an object, assigning it to an instance variable, then releasing it. It also appears that you're also leaking the object that was previously assigned to it since you don't explicitly release it. (Maybe it's autoreleased, can't tell here).

In the second example, you're allocating an object, and assigning it to a property that is retaining it. This means you're going to leak it unless you explicitly release/autorelease it.

```
self.myMemberVariable = [[[MyMemberVariable alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or

```
MyMemberVariable *m = [[MyMemberVariable alloc] init];
self.myMemberVariable = m;
[m release];
```

It's much better to use properties as you get (most) memory management for free. For example, you won't have to worry about freeing a reference before assigning a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The first form does not use properties. I don't see a good reason not to do:

```
[myMemberVariable release];
myMemberVariable = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

Since the old value is definitely not the same as the new one, so there is no chance any old value is released before it can be retained again.

Properties have the advantage that, in newer compilers, they are synthesized by the compiler and simply do the right thing, i.e. they know how to retain the new and release the old value, if the type is one that must be retained or copied. This is not necessary for types like int, float, etc., since these are simple value types.

In other words, if you use dot notation, either on self or on some other object, you access the property and in fact call either the getter or setter methods, depending on the direction of assignment.

If you access the ivar (member variable) directly, you don't have the protection from the property and have to code retain/release yourself.

You can also write your own setters and getters, and then you'll also have to take care of memory management, where it applies. It does, however, give you more flexibility. You could log items, check the validity of the input, update internal state variables, etc.